# How to run a Django project with .pyc files without using source codes?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pyc

I have a django project and i want to create the .pyc files and remove the source code. My project folder name is `mysite` and I ran the command `python -m compileall mysite`. The .pyc files are created. After that i tried to run my project with `python __pycache__/manage.cpython-37.pyc runserver` command but i've got an error such as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'`

There are two things I would like to ask about this. First, how can I solve this problem and run my project with .pyc file? Secondly, is it enough to move the .pyc files created to a separate folder in accordance with the django project structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I created a new folder in another directory such as a new django project and i created my `app` folders, `static` folder, `templates` folder etc. manually as the same as my django project architecture that I created before.

Then, I moved the .pyc files that I created with the compileall command to my new project folders.

As you know, while creating .pyc files, a `.cpython-37` section is added to the file names automatically (for example, `manage.py -> manage.cpython-37.pyc`). I removed that section and i converted them to `manage.pyc`, `views.pyc`, etc.

So my file structure was like this:

```
mysite/
    manage.pyc
    mysite/
        __init__.pyc
        settings.pyc
        urls.pyc
        wsgi.pyc
    app/
        migrations/
                __init__.pyc
        __init__.pyc
        admin.pyc
        apps.pyc
        models.pyc
        tests.pyc
        views.pyc

        ...
```

After I created this django project structure with .pyc files, i ran the `python manage.pyc runserver` command and it works.